# UITableView Only Lags On Scroll Down

Tags: ios, uitableview, lag

I have created a UITableView using a **prototype cell** containing labels and an 2 images.  Only 1 image is displayed per cell, and the image is stored locally and is static.  Upon loading, the user is at the bottom of the tableview.  For some reason, the UITableView performs perfectly upon loading as well as when scrolling up.  However, **when scrolling down**, the UITableView lags pretty badly.  So far I am at a lost to as why this happens, especially since scrolling up has zero lag.

**Even if I remove some elements from the prototype cell, including the images, it does not have an apparent impact on performance.**  Also commenting out the lines within cellForRowAtIndexPath (excluding first and last line) does not increase the speed of scrolling down.

```
#pragma mark UITableView Delegate
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return messages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MessagingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];
    if (!messages.count)
        return cell;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    ConvoParseData *convoParseData = [ConvoParseData new];
    NSString *sender = [convoParseData retreiveUsersNameFromArray:users withUserId:[[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sender"]];
    NSDate *date = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"date"];
    NSString *dateString = [convoParseData convoDateString:date];
    NSData *messageData = [[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"emoji"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *messageMeaning = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"meaning"];

    if (![[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"meaning2"] isEqualToString:@"nil"]) {
        messageMeaning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", messageMeaning, [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"meaning2"]];
    }
    if (![[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"meaning3"] isEqualToString:@"nil"]) {
        messageMeaning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", messageMeaning, [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"meaning3"]];
    }
    NSString *emoji = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    int emojiCount = [emoji componentsSeparatedByString:@"   "].count;
    emoji = [emoji stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"   " withString:@""];
    cell.userMeaning.text = nil;
    [cell.userMeaning setHidden:YES];
    cell.friendMeaning.text = nil;
    [cell.friendMeaning setHidden:YES];

    //        If User
    if ([[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"sender"] isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
        cell.friendBubble.image = nil;
        cell.friendName.text = nil;
        cell.friendMessage.text = nil;
        cell.friendDate.text = nil;
        cell.userBubble.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_bubble_user.png"];
        cell.userDate.text = dateString;
        cell.userMessage.text = emoji;
        cell.userMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nil size:28];
        if (emojiCount == 3) {
            cell.userMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nil size:14];
        }
    } else {
        //            If Friend
        cell.userBubble.image = nil;
        cell.userMessage.text = nil;
        cell.userDate.text = nil;

        cell.friendName.text = sender;
        cell.friendDate.text = dateString;
        cell.friendMessage.text = emoji;
        cell.friendMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nil size:28];
        if (emojiCount == 3) {
            cell.friendMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nil size:14];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Image: First pair of humps are from the app starting up.  The space between there and the final large hump was navigating to the UITableView.  The final hump was scrolling down (approx. 60 cells).  **Allocations** never exceeded **20 mb**.  On the final hump, **Time Profiler** mostly stayed in the range of **60% - 80%** and the **Sampler** often hit **40% - 80%**.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler?  I'm guessing that it takes a lot of time initializing the custom cell. ... I know you said that you tried removing elements, but without seeing the prototype that's my first guess.

Comment: It's a good idea to post how you implemented MessagingTableViewCell

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question in response to both of you.

Comment: Scrolling up has zero lag because the cells already exist, whereas when you scroll down you are dequeuing/creating brand new cells. Without looking any further into the code, that is very likely why there's a performance hit when scrolling down and not up.

Comment: Two more quick notes, normally numberOfRowsInSection should return an NSInteger, not an int, and you can simply return messages.count without using the if-statement, as if the array is empty or is nil that resolves to 0.

Comment: @Mike I forgot to mention this above and updated the question.  The tableview starts at the bottom, not the top.  So I would image that scrolling up with be when the new cells are created?  Also even when I scroll up and down multiple times, it is only when scrolling down that the lag occurs.

Comment: What does the retreiveUsersNameFromArray method do? There are a few things that could improve the way you're implementing the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Let me see if I can start a chat, if you have a few minutes.

Comment: If you have a few minutes: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61429/room-for-jeremy-herrero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there is not really an easy answer to this, but the solution Mike helped me work out involves shifting away from the Storyboard Prototype Cell and instead programmatically creating the cells via a cell class.  Big shout out to Mike for giving me this solution!

Here's the new code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MessagingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[MessagingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];

    cell.message = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell; 
}
```

MessagingTableViewCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (!_cellGenerated) {
        [self generateCell];
        _cellGenerated = YES;
    }

    [self resetCell];
}

- (void)generateCell {
//  Is only called the first time the cell is created
//  Static properties; properties that are the same for all cells, such as font size and color
}

- (void)resetCell {
//  Is called as the tableview reloads data
//  Any property that can be different for each cell, such as text
}
```

Comment: Whatever you `generateCell` does, `layoutSubviews` is the wrong place to perform these actions.

Comment: Opps!  I'm guessing you're referring to the .h typo I had up there.  Just corrected it.

Comment: No I was referring to your implementation. You should not generate (add subviews?) the cell inside `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Is there another approach?  Actually this isn't quite the answer it seems.  It helped performance on the iPhone simulator, but on my physical iPhone 5 the tableview still lags only when scrolling from top to bottom, every time.

Comment: I wasn't saying this is the answer, hence the comment and not an answer. I just wanted to tell you that you are using `-layoutSubviews` wrong.

Comment: Just to follow up, which I forgot to do right away, I ended up rebuilding the tableview all together using the code above.  The issue as to what was wrong is still a mystery to me.